# Detecting 2 swipes without interrupting touch

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I am trying to implement game control that will be changes direction of unit
movement. So if i do right swipe it turns to the right, if i do down swipe it turns to the down direction etc.

It's cocos2d game, and i'am using `CCNode+SFGestureRecognizers` with `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`.

At now I have next implementation for it

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRightSwipe:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:rightSwipeGestureRecognizer];
        rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
        rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [rightSwipeGestureRecognizer release];
        
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *upSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleUpSwipe:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:upSwipeGestureRecognizer];
        upSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
        upSwipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [upSwipeGestureRecognizer release];
        
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLeftSwipe:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:leftSwipeGestureRecognizer];
        leftSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
        leftSwipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [leftSwipeGestureRecognizer release];
        
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *downSwipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDownSwipe:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:downSwipeGestureRecognizer];
        downSwipeGestureRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
        downSwipeGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [downSwipeGestureRecognizer release];
```

but the problem is that for to recognize the following gesture you need to lift your finger from the screen. if you do not lift a finger after the first swipe, it will recognize only the first swipe.

**at now:**

[image]

**How it should be:**

[image]

What the best way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with cocos2d, but it sounds like you'd be better off tracking the touches yourself and determining the direction by keeping track of previous x,y and current x,y.  A swipe gesture is usually a fixed cycle gesture (you do it once) and doesn't trigger for continuous motion (otherwise everything would be a swipe).  In standard UIKit you have touchesMoved: method which gets called whenever a touch moves on the screen.  Not sure what the cocos2d equivalent is, but it might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, there is my solution. I dont think that is really good solution, but in my case it works, because i need getting direction at every time interval.

So, in my `CCLayer` subclass:

```
#define SWIPE_LENGTH        60
#define SWIPE_TANGENT       2

...

@property(nonatomic, assign) CGPoint latestLocation;

...

-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init]) )
        {
            self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
        }
    return self;
}

- (void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    self.latestLocation = location;
}

- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
    CGPoint delataLocation = CGPointMake(location.x - self.latestLocation.x, location.y - self.latestLocation.y);
    if ( sqrt(pow((delataLocation.x), 2) + pow((delataLocation.y), 2) ) > SWIPE_LENGTH ) {
        if (delataLocation.y > 0 && delataLocation.y > SWIPE_TANGENT * ABS(delataLocation.x))
        {
            [self handleSwipeWithDirestion:SDirectionTypeUp];
        } else if (delataLocation.y < 0 && ABS(delataLocation.y) > SWIPE_TANGENT * ABS(delataLocation.x))
        {
            [self handleSwipeWithDirestion:SDirectionTypeDown];
        } else if (delataLocation.x > 0 && delataLocation.x > SWIPE_TANGENT * ABS(delataLocation.y))
        {
            [self handleSwipeWithDirestion:SDirectionTypeRight];
        } else if (delataLocation.x < 0 && ABS(delataLocation.x) > SWIPE_TANGENT * ABS(delataLocation.y))
        {
            [self handleSwipeWithDirestion:SDirectionTypeLeft];
        }
        self.latestLocation = location;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[cancelsTouchesInView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/cancelsTouchesInView) should help, it prevents the cancellation of touch events when a gesture recognizer has recognized a gesture. This will allow other gesture recognizers to continue checking for their gesture.

```
  rightSwipeGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
  upSwipeGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
  leftSwipeGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
  downSwipeGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution doesn't working in my case. Maybe it not works because of implementation of CCNode+SFGestureRecognizers.h. I will explore this

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `UIGestureRecognizer` like so:

```swift
class CustomSwipeGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer {
    private var prevLocation = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    public var dir = ""

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let location = touch?.location(in: self.view) ?? CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        prevLocation = location
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first
        let location = touch?.location(in: self.view) ?? CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        let deltaX = location.x - prevLocation.x
        let deltaY = location.y - prevLocation.y
        let isVertical   = abs(deltaY) > (1.2 * abs(deltaX))
        let isHorizontal = abs(deltaX) > (1.2 * abs(deltaY))
        let distance = sqrt(pow(deltaX, 2) + pow(deltaY, 2))
        if (distance <= 60) {
            return
        }
        if (isVertical) {
            dir = deltaY > 0 ? "down" : "up"
            prevLocation = location
            state = .changed
        } else if (isHorizontal) {
            dir = deltaX > 0 ? "right" : "left"
            prevLocation = location
            state = .changed
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        state = .ended
    }
    
    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        state = .cancelled
    }
}
```

And use it in your view controller like so:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let swipeGesture = CustomSwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onSwipe))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
    }

    @objc func onSwipe(sender: CustomSwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        // this callback is called repeatedly with every movement, even when the gesture recognizer has not changed state
        if (sender.dir == "") {
            return
        }
        print(sender.dir)
        sender.dir = ""
    }

}
```